# React Native - navigation issue "undefined is not an object (this.props.navigation.navigate)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Im following this tutorial https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/  and im running into a bit of issues.

Im using the Expo Client app to render my app every time and not a simulator/emulator.

my code is seen down below.

I originally had the  "SimpleApp" const defined above "ChatScreen" component  but that gave me the following error:

> Route 'Chat' should declare a screen. For example: ...etc

so I moved the decleration of SimpleApp to just above "AppRegistry" and that flagged a new error

> Element type is invalid: expected string.....You likely forgot to export your component..etc

the tutorial did not add the key words "export default" to any  component which I think it may have to do with the fact that im running it on the Expo app? so I added "export default" to "HomeScreen" and the error went away.

The new error that I cant seem to get rid off(based on the code below) is the following:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

I can't get rid of it unless I remove the "{}" around "const {navigate}" but that will break the navigation when I press on the button from the home screen

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Text,Button} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}



class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

Comment: Seems like this.props.navigation is undefined when first rendered. You can try removing the line `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` and using `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat')}` so it will access the object only later.

Comment: I tried that, I got prompted to press on the button, but when i did i ran in to this error, "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')"
And I do have react-navigation npm module installed

Comment: For me the navigation works fine, just needed to import View from react-native, but I am not running it in Expo.

Comment: If I was designing a navigation API to be as obtuse and fragile as possible, I could not do worse than React navigation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With Expo you should't do the App registration your self instead you should let Expo do it, keeping in mind that you have to export default component always:
Also you need to import View and Button from react-native: please find below the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

 class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat', { user: 'Lucy' })}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

 class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  // Nav options can be defined as a function of the screen's props:
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}`,
  });
  render() {
    // The screen's current route is passed in to `props.navigation.state`:
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with {params.user}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const  SimpleAppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen }
});

const AppNavigation = () => (
  <SimpleAppNavigator  />
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigation/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! 
Can you elaborate more on the part where i shouldn't do appregistration myself with expo ?
And just to confirm, I always need to export a default component WHICH will be rendered initially ?
Also, Any reason you made AppNavigation and instance of SimpleAppNavigator ?  is this best practice?

Comment: so normally if you are testing without Expo you would register your app with for example:
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);`
But with Expo it will take the root Component exported as default and it will show it in the Expo app:
 'export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigation/>
    );
  }
}'
don't forget to mark the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: done! could you also explain why you placed the simpleAppNavigator into AppNavigation and then rendered into a different component ? is that best practice?

Comment: Here it might look not important.. but in general you wanna have this separation.. because your navigator could be in another file only concerned with this part of the routing.. but your navigation could have extended logic like for example binding with the store with redux.. and also navigation could include a combination of a tab navigator and several stack navigators for example.

Comment: @AhmedKhaledA.Mohamed You are a god. The docs here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ are super outdated and the example is broken right out the box. You should be the one writing the example for them haha. Spent several hours on this error. Everyone on the internet is asking this question and are super confused and running in circles. Thanks man!! (bounty for you in 23 hours)

Comment: Haha thanks man I appreciate your kind words and I'm glad I could help! But believe me I'm no where close to the guys working on react-navigation, I wish I was haha! Thanks again.

Comment: thanks it works. but one thing is that when using flow it will give an error on:     const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

Comment: Can you please provide this working demo? I was looking for the same requirement...

Comment: Does not work anymore. `Module '"./node_modules/react-navigation/typescript/react-navigation"' has no exported member 'StackNavigator'.`

Comment: this.props.navigation gives me this problem: Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>

Answer (score 37):

Additional Info: 
When you are nesting child components, you need to pass navigation as prop in parent component.
//parent.js
`<childcomponent navigation={this.props.navigation}/>`

And you can access navigation like this

//child.js

[image]
`this.props.navigation.navigate('yourcomponent');`

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me in my initial struggle with react-native to solve the undefined error

Comment: This worked for me thank you! I assumed that because I had created a screen for my component that it would receive the `props.navigation` however it wasn't because that component was nested in another one, not sure why that is. So I just passed it like you said.

Comment: Ouch, I don't like having to do this, maybe it'd be nice to have it in a context. Edit: We can call `useNavigation` which is nice because we don't have to pass props down the component hierarchy

Answer (score 6):

As Bobur has said in his answer, the navigation prop isn't passed to children of the routed component. To give your components access to `navigation` you can pass it as a prop to them, BUT there is a better way.

If you don't want to pass the `navigation` prop all the way down your component hierarchy, you can use `useNavigation` instead. (Which in my opinion is just cleaner anyways, and reduces the amount of code we have to write):

```js
function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

This is just really nice because if you have multiple levels of components you wont have to continuously pass the navigation object as props just to use it. Passing `navigation` just once requires us to 1. Add a prop to the component we want to pass it to. 2. Pass the prop from the parent component. 3. Use the `navigation` prop to navigate. Sometimes we have to repeat steps 1 and 2 to pass the prop all the way down to the component that needs to use `navigation`. We can condense steps 1 and 2, no matter how many times they are repeated, into a single `useNavigation` call with this method.

I think it is best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code: `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat')}`

Answer (score 0):

<ChildComponent **navigation={props.navigation}** {...data} />

This will make the navigation from the parent propagated to the subsequent child navigations.

Answer (score -8):

```
const AppNavigation =()=>{  <SimpleApp  />}

export default class App extends React.Componet{
   render(){
      return (
        <AppNavigation/>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding explanations to your answer.

Comment: And take away the typo's from your code: "Componet"...