# undefined is not an object 'this2.props.navigation.navigate'

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am not able to navigate on another page.
I have default class code
in this class, navigation is working fine

```
export default class ClassName1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```

but when I call `this.props.navigation` on the below class it throws an error

```
class ClassName2 extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }
}
```

like this I am calling the function in `ClassName2`

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Report") }>
    <Text style={style.modalContainerText}>
         inappropriate Content
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

both classes are in one file.

Comment: your screens must be both on a Stack, tab or drawer navigator so you navigate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - navigation issue "undefined is not an object (this.props.navigation.navigate)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678552/react-native-navigation-issue-undefined-is-not-an-object-this-props-navigati)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but I guess you are using `ClassName2` like this inside of `ClassName1` (with some more components and the constructor ofcourse):

```
class ClassName1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <ClassName2 />
    }
}
```

Now I guess you are using `ClassName1` as a route with react-navigation. The `ClassName1` component gets the `this.props.navigation` prop automatically by react-navigation. To pass it to the `ClassName2` element, so it can also call navigation, would be like this:

```
class ClassName1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <ClassName2 navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    }
}
```

This is based on guesses though, so let me know if this is what would solves your problem. If so, I will update your question to provide the info that would describe your problem better :)

Comment: it worked! but by applying this on render it didn't execute below code and return.

Comment: You need to replace the `<ClassName2 />` inside your original render with the `<ClassName2 navigation={this.props.navigation} />` one :)

Answer (score 0):

If your class is included inside the `StackNavigator` function you'll have access to `this.props.navigation` if not you have to use `withNavigation` function like bellow

**Example using `StackNavigator`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export class ClassName2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title="This will work" onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('someScreen') }} />;
  }
}

export const myStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  myScreen: ClassName2
})
```

**Example using `withNavigation`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class ClassName2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title="This will work" onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('someScreen') }} />;
  }
}

export default withNavigation(ClassName2);
```

Comment: by using withNavigation  it throws error syntax error: only one default export allowed per module.
because i am already using ClassName1  as export and default

Comment: @talhaabdulhameed don't copy and paste this code, it's just an example.

Comment: is `ClassName2` used inside  `ClassName1`? if so you can use it like that `<ClassName2 navigation={this.props.navigation} />` otherwise replace the default export with named export